# Create an autoscroll slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've found [this accordion slider](http://jc-designs.net/blog/2011/07/how-to-build-a-horizontal-jquery-accordion/) which fits my needs, [see demo](http://www.jc-designs.net/demo/accordion.html), but it doesn't start sliding automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  activePanel = $("#accordion div.panel:first");
  $(activePanel).addClass('active');

  $("#accordion").delegate('.panel', 'click', function(e){
    if( ! $(this).is('.active') ){
        $(activePanel).animate({width: "44px"}, 300);
        $(this).animate({width: "848px"}, 300);
        $('#accordion .panel').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        activePanel = this;
    };
  });
});
```

and here's all the code on jsfiddle if it helps (although even after changing the widths it's not displaying right): http://jsfiddle.net/wamcbrf3/

I've tried adding this which hasn't helped:

```
autoPlay: {
   enabled: true,
   delay: 1500
}
```

I'm a jquery newbie so any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed some missing HTML and the widths so I could see the slider correctly in my screen (reduced all widths by 400px). Still there were a couple of things missing from the fiddle:

- You didn't include jQuery.
- There was only one panel, so no possible sliding.

After **fixing these 2 things, the slider is working fine** (you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wamcbrf3/1/)

For the **autoplay**, I have created a small function:

```
function animatePanels() {
    // select the next active panel
    nextPanel = $("#accordion div.panel.active").next();
    // if the length is 0: we were at the last panel, so select the first one instead
    if (nextPanel.length == 0) { nextPanel = $("#accordion div.panel:first"); } 
    // click on the panel to trigger the animation
    $(nextPanel).click();
}
```

Then, you just need to call the function at the end `$(document).ready(...)` with a `setInterval` to have the animation start automatically (change 2500 for the time that you want in milliseconds):

```
setInterval("animatePanels()", 2500);
```

You can see a running example on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wamcbrf3/4/